# How to set Table view cell to occupy entire screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, swift3

I am working on a project to get custom news feeds from Bing news. I created a custom table view cell and populated various UI items in it. But I am having a hard time to make it occupy the entire screen, it starts from extreme left and ends on the right, leaving large gap from the right margin as show in the image. Can anyone help me out, how to correctly fix it with a detailed explanation of how constraints work in Table views and Tableview cells.

[Here' what it looks like in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NPIu.jpg)

Comment: `I am having a hard time to make it occupy the entire screen` did you mean width or height, What you want cell to occupy whole width or height or both ?

Comment: I want it to occupy entire width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove previous constraints and add constraint to your `UITableView` like as shown in below image.
So you `UITableView` will have **0** margin from edges.

[image]

Comment: Still the issue persist.  [Here's the screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/EbWGD)

Comment: Actually it was the problem with Auto resizing, editing it solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UITableViewController`. Just drag drop a `TableViewCell` into it. Add identifier for that cell and use it. By default it will occupy the whole screen.

In your case I guess you might have added constraints to `UITableView`. Here what you should do is pin your `UITableView` to Top,Bottom,Right & Left or make `UITableView`'s width equal to SuperView.

Comment: I have no constraints set, I am using a tableview in a view controller.

Comment: Actually it was the problem with Auto resizing, editing it solved the issue. Thanks a lot